# matching files to folders

Tags: linux

Can linux scan two directories? Once scanned match the two directories based on similarities in the file name and transfer files.

I'm looking to transfer file  "directory"/seq0001.pdf to folder "different directory"/001 and "directory"/seq0002.pdf to folder "different directory"/002
e.t.c

When newly incremented file number is created I would like to move that new file to the new directory.

The new folder doesn't need to be made. As when there is a new file some other job is putting information in this folder and creates the new folder.

I know how to do a straight move function but that would only work for the specified files.
Can you move the files by a match rather than having to manually move the files every time?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a way to shorten this (actually, there are a ton of good alternatives for parsing the file name; check out [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138634/shortest-way-to-extract-last-3-characters-of-base-minus-suffix-filename) - I will update here as soon as I get a chance), but one way is to first create a script that handles a single file. For example, save the following as `move.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
subdir=`echo -n "${1%.*}" | tail -c3`
mv -v "$1" "/path/to/$subdir"
```

Adjust to taste. That will take take the part of the filename before the last "." and use the rightmost three characters as the target directory (e.g. "seq0002.pdf" goes to "/path/to/002").

The `chmod 755 move.sh` to make it executable.

I recommend putting that script in a different directory so it doesn't interfere. Then you can use e.g. `find` to execute it on all files, or just run it on one file at a time, e.g.:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec /wherever/move.sh {} \;
```

Or for one file (and assuming move.sh is in current directory):

```
./move.sh seq0001.pdf
```

If you want to choose more complex paths you can extend the script, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/sh
subdir=`echo -n "${1%.*}" | tail -c3`

if [ $subdir = "001" ] ; then
    rootdir="/directory";
elif [ $subdir = "002" ] ; then
    rootdir="/another/place";
else
    rootdir="/default/root";
fi

mv -v "$1" "$rootdir/$subdir"
```

Again adjusting to taste. The possibilities are fairly limitless.